# onChange inside of both compent & child

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an `onChange` function inside of my `<Textarea>` component but I also need to pass in a separate `onChange` function when it is deployed. I need the text change calculator to work at the same time as being able to pass in the `onChange` function that is inside of the `App`.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function Textarea(props) {
  const [textCount, settextCount] = useState(0);
  const { id } = props;

  const recalculate = (e) => {
    settextCount(e.target.value.length);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <textarea type="text" id={id} onChange={recalculate} />
      <p>{textCount}/5</p>
    </>
  );
}
export default Textarea;

const App = (props) => {
  const change = async (e) => {
    props.changevalue(e);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <Textarea id={id} onChange={change}/>
      <Textarea id={id} />
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: remove `async` from `const change = async (e) => ...`. it is only needed when `await` is used in the function body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do that by passing the event of the `textarea` changing to the two functions at the same time, like so:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

function Textarea(props) {
  const [textCount, settextCount] = useState(0);
  const { id } = props;

  const recalculate = (e) => {
    settextCount(e.target.value.length);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <textarea
        type="text"
        id={id}
        onChange={(e) => {
          recalculate(e);
          props.onChange(e);
        }}
      />
      <p>{textCount}/5</p>
    </>
  );
}
export default Textarea;
```

```js
const App = (props) => {
  const change = async (e) => {
    props.changevalue(e);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <Textarea id={id} onChange={change} />
      <Textarea id={id} />
    </>
  );
};
```